# C# multithreaded merging of big number of XML documents

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, merge, parallel-processing

I have some code that merges XML documents. It can merge as many documents as needed but gets a bit slow once the number starts to increase.

```
    private string MergeList(List<string> documents)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < documents.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: // Do nothing on first elapse
                    break;
                case 1: // Use first and second
                    result = Merge(documents[0], documents[i]);
                    break;
                default: // Now just keep merging until no more documents in list
                    result = Merge(result,documents[i]);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is there any clever way to do this multithreaded? All I need to is end up having all documents merged into the same string. The order in which they are merged does not matter.

I could imagine there must be some kind of pattern to do this?

Comment: What does `Merge` do? Simple string concatenation or something more complex?

Comment: How about beginning your loop at index 1 instead of 0?

Comment: It merges the two XML documents - not rocket science merge - but not just simple concatenation either. Looks for elements that exists in one and not the other, changes some references etc.

Comment: Scoregraphic - yeah good point, but it won't help my overall question.

Comment: That's why I added it as a comment ;-)

Comment: @Jesper if `Merge` is not trivial, you can gain some performance improvement by using some kind of parallelism, like this provided in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, for simplicity, that you have some Merging function (here is only concatenation, you can of course have here XML processing etc.):

```
public static string Merge(string a, string b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

you can create a set of `Task<>` by recursion by splitting input collection into two and merging them recursively. It can be seen as creating an **awaitable graph of `Tasks`**:

```
public static async Task<string> MergeRecursive(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    if (strings.Count() == 1)
        return strings.First();
    // Here we make a real merging
    if (strings.Count() == 2)
        return Merge(strings.First(), strings.Last());

    var parts = strings.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                       .GroupBy(g => g.i % 2, g => g.s, (k, v) => v)
                       .ToList();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(parts.Select(p => Task.Run(() => MergeRecursive(p))));
    return await MergeRecursive(results);
}
```

then you can get result:

```
List<string> documents = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    documents.Add(i.ToString("X"));

var merge = MergeRecursive(documents).Result;
```

For such case Concurrency Visualizer shows 5 working CLR threads doing merges in parallel.

Comment: This looks just like what I am looking for - I will test it and get back.

Comment: In case of and odd number of documents, what happens ? If one docuement is assigned to two others, you have to make sure that Merge() is thread-safe.

Comment: @C4stor, first `if` takes care of subcollections which will happen with odd number of documents

Comment: Ahh this is .net 4.5 I am using 4.0. But as I control all of it, perhaps I should consider a switch to 4.5.

Comment: I get a StackOverflowException on your:  var parts = strings.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                       .GroupBy(g => g.i % 2, g => g.s, (k, v) => v)
                       .ToList();

Comment: @Jesper, how big is your collection and how stack trace looks?

Comment: Ahh that was with 0 in the collection - that's easy to test for and avoid. There seems to be an performance advantage in the "sequential" up to about 4 - from there multithread rocks. Thanks a lot it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to set `List<string>` documents to global and add a `BackgroundWorker` and set the event `DoWork` to a function that merges the documents and the event `RunWorkCompleted` to the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is just concatenating strings together then multithreading is probably overkill. Instead, use a StringBuffer and precalculate the size in order to avoid memory reallocations:

```
private string MergeList(List<string> documents)
{
  int size=0;

  foreach(var doc in documents)
  {
    size+=doc.Length;
  }

  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(size);

  foreach(var doc in documents)
  {
    buffer.append(doc);
  }

  return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It is more complex than just string concatenation. It merges elements from the two documents, changes references etc.